# Is the Unicode Byte Order Mark allowed at the start of a UNIX script file?

Tags: linux, unix, unicode, byte-order-mark

A `#!` at the start of an executable file tells Unix/Linux shells to treat the file as a script, and the path to the interpreter for this script immediately follows the `#!`.

Is it legal for a Unicode Byte Order Mark to appear at the start of such script file before the `#!`?

I understand that the particular interpreter that the script will be passed to will need to understand the Byte Order Mark and process it correctly. My question is whether the `#!` part is still considered to be at the start of the file?

Of course, I could go out and test what a particular shell on a particular OS does, but I am interested in a more general question on whether this is legal. If someone could link or point to a document that would be fantastic!

Comment: If you put a BOM at the start of the file, the kernel won't recognize the `#!` shebang.  Further, there's no point in a BOM; if the file is UTF-8, the BOM is pointless, and I know of no kernel that works with UTF-16 (or UTF-32) as a Unicode representation, and those are where a BOM might be relevant.  So, in summary — don't put a BOM at the start of a file on Unix; it won't help and will probably hinder things.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. The BOM would be for the benefit of the interpreter that eventually runs the script.

Comment: If the data in the script file really is UTF-16 (UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE), then the BOM can appear at the start and can inform the interpreter of the script, but the kernel won't launch the interpreter for you; you'd have use `interpreter script.name` instead of just typing `script.name` (and you'd probably have to deal with path locations for the script, too).  That's fine as long as you recognize that's what'll happen.  If you want to run just `script.name`, then the file must start with `#!` which precludes a BOM as an alternative start.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

If you put a BOM at the start of the file, the kernel won't recognize the `#!` shebang. Further, there's no point in a BOM; if the file is UTF-8, the BOM is pointless, and I know of no kernel that works with UTF-16 (or UTF-32) as a Unicode representation, and those encodings are where a BOM might be relevant. So, in summary — don't put a BOM at the start of a file on Unix; it won't help and will probably hinder things.

> The BOM would be for the benefit of the interpreter that eventually runs the script.

If the data in the script file really is UTF-16 (UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE), then the BOM can appear at the start and can inform the interpreter of the script, but the kernel won't launch the interpreter for you; you'd have use:

```
interpreter script.name
```

instead of just typing

```
script.name
```

(and you'd probably have to deal with path locations for the script, too). That's fine as long as you recognize that's what'll happen. If you want to run just `script.name`, then the file must start with `#!` which precludes a BOM as an alternative start.